# Embed a Windows shared clickable path in the mail

Tags: email, shell-script

I want to send a mail by embedding a clickable link to a shared windows NAS path.
I checked solutions where we can use something like `"<html><body><a href=`

But I am not sure how to put that for a NAS shared drive.
Below is my drive name:

```
\\Nas30u0r2b.fdc.crab.com\DPT_pp_data\logs\PP\Target.
```

Comment: Which email client and operating system?

Comment: Didn't get you. I want to write a unix shell script for the same either through mailx or sendmail etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the usual HTML syntax for hyperlinks:

```
<a href="file://Nas30u0r2b.fdc.crab.com/DPT_pp_data/logs/PP/Target">Target title</a>
```

However, whether this hyperlink will open the file manager,
or whether it will not, depends entirely on the receiving email client,
the antivirus and other safeguards.

If the hyperlink opens instead in the Internet browser, success will then depend on
the browser and on its security settings. Some browsers
will call the file manager in such a case, others will display the folder themselves,
while still others will issue an error.

Comment: This is redirecting to a page which has link like below:
http://nas30u0r2b.fdc.crab.comDPT_dq_pp_datalogspptarget/

Comment: I think we need to put some escape sequence

Comment: It worked for me, but a more general formulation might be like this: `file://Nas30u0r2b.fdc.crab.com/DPT_pp_data/logs/PP/Target`, where `Nas30u0r2b.fdc.crab.com` is the name of the computer housing the share. For local file reference use `file:///`. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: Great!!. This Worked Perfect!!